# Is it possible to substring a string, but keep the whole string hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, substr

I am trying to cut down the visible length of a string to about 25 characters. I want to keep the whole string on the page. Hidden of course.

```
<span>This message is 34 characters long</span>

$("span").text(function(index, text) {
    return text.substr(0, 25);
});
```

Will return

```
This message is 34 charac
```

Where I want it to write **This message is 34 charac** but keep the rest of the characters hidden, so I can display them later using **.show()** or something else.

Comment: you can set an attribute or property to the origional text and recover it using that property later.

Comment: or use css: white-space:pre; width: 25em; overflow:hidden; display: inline-block;

Comment: @dandavis Font-size is not letter-width: http://jsfiddle.net/V2h2F/ :)
Ok, half the em per letter and you are in! http://jsfiddle.net/BnSzE/ ;) You could also do the `ellipsis` thing.

Comment: @dandavis Stop: does not work with letters http://jsfiddle.net/XQpLZ/. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store it in jQuery's `data()`

```
$("span").text(function(index, text) {
    $(this).data('txt', text);
    return text.substr(0, 25);
});
```

Later you can just do

```
$("span").text(function() {
    return $(this).data('txt');
});
```

Comment: @Snorlax - Thanks! Being the owner of my own nuclear power plant, I don't really need cookies, Smithers buys those for me, but accepting the answer sure would be nice ?

Comment: Lmao. Up for laugh there. Will accept once I can (two more minutes I believe). EDIT: One minute!

Answer (score 1):

You could write the whole string to a html element of it's own that has a style of display: none. You could also add a data attribute to the span tag as well.

Comment: Had this same thought

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span").html(function(index, text) {
    return text.substr(0,25) + '<span style="display:none">' + text.substr(25) +'</span>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the string to a data attribute:

```
<span data-text="This message is 34 characters long"></span>

$("span").text(function(index, text) {
  return $(this).data('text').substr(0, 25);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c3qW4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS property:
Select the div where you save the string like this

```
  <div>My String</div>
  <style>
  div{
     width: 50px;
     overflow: hidden;/* this will hide all the content that surpass the width */
  }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the unwanted part in a hidden span, so I could use `.toggle()` on it after.

```
$('span').html(function(index, oldHtml) {
        return oldHtml.substring(0,25) + '<span class="toggleHidden">' + text.substr(25) + '</span>';
});

$('.toggleHidden').toggle();
```

Note the use of `.html()` instead of `.text()` as the first one allows me to set HTML elements as children.